# How to use runner.py in sumo via command line and solving its common error(permission denied)

Tags: python, sumo

When I try to use the runner.py example via the command line, I encounter the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\doc\tutorial\traci_tls>runner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\doc\tutorial\traci_tls\runner.py", line 122, in 
generate_routefile()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\doc\tutorial\traci_tls\runner.py", line 47, in generate_routefile
with open("data/cross.rou.xml", "w") as routes:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data/cross.rou.xml'

Who knows how to solve this error?
Regards, Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a local copy of the tutorial to your home directory before running it. You probably do not have write access to the installation directory.

Comment: I'm sorry Michael for my late reply. Thank you indeed. It works as you said.